# Why can't Unity inject a concrete container implementation instead of IUnityContainer?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

So here is the situation: when I inject an `IUnityContainer` into a constructor somewhere, things work *just fine*. However, what I do instead is *inherit* from a `UnityContainer`, i.e.

```
class Services : UnityContainer
```

Now, when I inject `Services`, I get the class but all its registrations are lost :(

I can, of course, inject `IUnityContainer` and cast it to `Services` (it works), but I'd rather just inject `Services` to begin with.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** by popular demand, here is some source code:

```
class Services : UnityContainer
{
  // some of my personal stuff here; nothing important
}

// later, in Program.cs
IUnityContainer uc = new Services();
services.RegisterType<Foo,Bar>();
Application.Run(services.Resolve<MainFrame>());

// and then, elsewhere
class Test
{
  public Test(Services svcs)
  {
    var bar = svcs.Resolve<Foo>(); // this fails - no registration in svcs
  }

  // on the other hand, this works just fine:
  public Test(IUnityContainer svcs)
  {
    var s = (Services)svcs;
    var bar = s.Resolve<Foo>(); // works just fine
  }
}
```

Comment: Not clear for me what are you trying to accomplish. Show us some code please.

Comment: this is the normal behavior. i´m not sure what you expect

Comment: Services IS a UnityContainer? Are your sure this is correct? Why do you use inheritance?

Comment: Added some sample code.

Comment: Note that as you are injecting unity itself in a constructor, you make it a first class citizen; while it should be an invisible one in order to not make you depend on it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829070/is-it-a-preferred-approach-to-inject-iunitycontainer-itself-as-an-argument-insid

Comment: L-Three is right. That is not a good DI aproach.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you would have to register `Services` like any other type. Unity container register `IUnityContainer` by default, that is why you can inject unity interface, but not your concrete implementation.

`services.RegisterInstance<Services>(services);` as part of registration code should do the trick.